# How to get hash fragment of URL from UIWebView

Tags: ios, hash, uiwebview, nsurl, fragment

I'm trying to get hash fragment of URL loaded in UIWebView, I have tried different approaches it does not seem to work.

For example if the UIWebView is loaded with "http://www.mysite.com/home#main":

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/home#main"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

then I want to get the full url, but it only return "http://www.mysite.com/home" with 3 different approaches:

1:

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView.request.URL absoluteString];
```

2:

```
NSString *currentURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[webView request] URL]];
```

3:

```
NSString *currentURL = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.hash"];
```

what am I missing

Comment: I think the problem is that the hash fragment is ignored by UIWebView, I'm able to get hash fragment if I do percent escape the url: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/home%23main"];  , but this is a solution if you are loading a known url, the problem is that if a link within a webpage has hash fragment then it wil be ignored by UIWebView

Comment: I do not think NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mysite.com/home%23main"]; can convert the %23 to "#"

Answer (score 2):

Try `NSString *fragment = [webView.request.URL fragment];`

Answer (score 1):

`[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.hash"]` is the only way I had success to get the hash fragment in my case

I failed on approaches 1 and approaches 2

maybe your code wrong on someway else......

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet 
 NSLog(@"Hash fragment :%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",webview.request.URL.fragment]);

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check that, request.url.absolutestring has fragment on  shouldStartLoadWithRequest, webViewDidFinishLoad.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to me, instead a standalone answer. You might want to check some tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/help