# How to load NSURL which contains hash fragment "#" with UIWebView?

Tags: nsurl

Given a local URL address like index.html

Now I need to use `UIWebView` to load it in iPad. I followed these steps:

1. Create NSURL

   ```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://mysite.com#page1"];
   ```
2. Load with UIWebView for local HTML/JS/CSS etc

   ```
   [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   ```

But it doesn't work, because "#" is converted to "%23", so the URL string is

`http://mysite.com%23page1`

My question is, how to fix this auto-conversion issue and let `UIWebView` access the URL which contains the hash fragment "#"?

Comment: Similar question [How to get hash fragment of URL from UIWebView][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408082/how-to-get-hash-fragment-of-url-from-uiwebview

Answer (score 15):

User **URLWithString** to append fragment to your url, like this:

```
*NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFilePath];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@", @"yourFragmentHere"] relativeToURL:url];*
```

Hope it will help :)

---

EDIT: Swift 3 version:

```
var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlFilePath)
url = URL(string: "#yourFragmentHere", relativeTo: url)
```

Comment: Save lots of time for people not familiar with Objective C

Comment: I had a problem with this format in iOS 12 when trying to load html from file url with a fragment. It did not load it for some reason. Instead I used `[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",url.absoluteString, @"#fragment"]];`

Answer (score 3):

for reference in swift:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "web")
var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
url = NSURL(string: "#URL_FRAGMENT", relativeToURL: url!)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
self.webView.loadRequest(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For swift 3** 
solution1:
You can call this line after webview loaded

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(fromString: "window.location.href = '#myHashtag'")
```

solution2:
also if you want to load directly use this

```
webView1.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url! + "#myHashtag")!))
```

**ObjC:**
solution 1:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
```

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href = '#myHashtag';"];
}

solution2:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@#myHashtag",myURL]]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not loading in web view because you are using wrong method to create a NSURL object, fileURLWithPath is used for a system path. Use this one -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com#page1"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

For more info about NSURL read documentation -

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The reason I used requestWithURL:url is to load local html file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my requirement is to load local html file. The idea is to build all html/js/css locally. Different requirement. Thanks

Comment: If want to load a local html file then why are using this @"http://mysite.com#page1" as path ?

Comment: Yes,I drag the whole package of html/js/css/resources into a blue folder in my iPad app project. You can treat those HTML as static package of online web system.

Comment: then you can create file path as NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]];