# Instagram client-auth missing #access_token after redirect

Tags: ios, safari, instagram, authentication

A previously working Instagram client-authentication flow recently broke due to missing access token after redirection

- https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://myapp.com/success&response_type=token&display=touch&scope=basic

Instagram properly redirects the user to myapp.com/success#access_token=some_token in Chrome.

However, when accessing the URL from within (iOS) client code / desktop Safari the redirect happens without any appended #access_token data

Comment: I had the same problem. [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332392/8214875) was hard to find but funnily easy.

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same issue with instagram client-implicit auth on iOS app, I think it is the iOS webview not allowing hash fragment. Here is my question from the past: [How to get hash fragment of URL from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408082/how-to-get-hash-fragment-of-url-from-uiwebview)

Comment: No luck with the solutions on that page, for me or its original author

Comment: If you paste the link to safari on your computer, the access_token is missing too, not only on iOS. But the same link works on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my site http://slidetagram.com

This is an known issue on Safari.

To fix this you have to add an extra slash before the # on your page to be redirected.

In my case I've changed from

`http://slidetagram.com/slide#access_token=...`

to

`http://slidetagram.com/slide/#access_token=...`

After that change, it worked fine!

Comment: It doesn't work for me! :( still missing access_token