# Implicit Auth. Flow - No Access Token Appended on Redirect - iOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, instagram, redirect, instagram-api

I made a web app with Instagram API that uses Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication.

I redirect the user to

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

and the Instagram log-in page appears. Normally, Instagram redirects the app to

```
http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

And I grab the access_token to use it in the app. This works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on my pc.

However, **the redirection doesn't work on my iPhone 6.** I tried both Chrome and Safari. **The redirected address turns out to be the one without #access_token appended**, i.e:

```
http://your-redirect-uri
```

Is it something to do with security and impossible to work, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the redirect URI has to end with a `/` for proper redirection on iOS.